# Чему эквивалентная запись js

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать смену второго параметра в зависимости от первого. Есть 5 типов ввода - text, image, textarea, ckeditor, checkbox

И в зависимости от выбранного типа ввода, выводить нужное поле - текстовое,поле загрузки и т.д.

Сделал вот так через show и hide, но получился большой одинаковый код

```
 $script = <<< JS
    $('.js-type').on('change',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val();
    switch(selection){   
    case "image":
    $("#image").show()
    $("#input").hide()
    $("#textarea").hide()
    $("#fck").hide()
    $("#checkbox").hide()
    break;

    case "input":
    $("#input").show()
    $("#image").hide()
    $("#textarea").hide()
    $("#fck").hide()
    $("#checkbox").hide()
    break;

    case "textarea":
    $("#textarea").show()
    $("#image").hide()
    $("#input").hide()
    $("#fck").hide()
    $("#checkbox").hide()
    break;

    case "fck":
    $("#fck").show()
    $("#textarea").hide()
    $("#image").hide()
    $("#input").hide()
    $("#checkbox").hide()
    break;

    case "checkbox":
    $("#checkbox").show()
    $("#image").hide()
    $("#textarea").hide()
    $("#fck").hide()
    $("#input").hide()
    break;
    }
});
JS;
```

И формы

```
<div id="input" style="display:none;">
                    <?=  $form->field($model, 'value')->textInput(); ?>
                </div>
                <div id="image" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'value')->fileInput(); ?>
                </div> .....
```

Как можно по другому записать такой скрипт??

Comment: Ну поместите все поля в какой-нибудь `div#wrap` и просто в начале скрипта написать `$('div#wrap > div').hide()` что спрячет все эти дивы с айдишниками а `$('div#'+ selection).show()` покажет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поместите все поля в какой-нибудь `div#wrap` и просто в начале скрипта пишите

```
$('div#wrap > div').hide()
```

что спрячет все эти дивы с айдишниками, а

```
$('#'+ selection).show()
```

покажет нужное поле.

Пример:

```js
$('.js-type').on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();

  $('div#wrap > div').hide();
  $("#"+selection).show();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="input" style="display:none;">
    111
  </div>
  <div id="image" style="display:none;">
    222
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" class="js-type" />
```

Пишем `input`, нажимаем <kbd>Enter</kbd> и опля!

Пишем `image`, нажимаем <kbd>Enter</kbd> и опля снова!

---

спешл эдишн для ТС с применением `select`:

```js
 $('.js-type').on('change', function() {
   var selection = $(this).val();

   $('div#wrap > div').hide();
   $("#" + selection).show();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="input" style="display:none;">
    input div
  </div>
  <div id="image" style="display:none;">
    image div
  </div>
</div>


<select class="js-type">
  <option>--none--</option>
  <option>input</option>
  <option>image</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасбо за ответ! Но все же хотелось бы чтобы была возможность выбора из списка

Comment: @VladShkuta в смысле из списка? ну поставьте вместо инпута select. Я же не запрещаю)

Comment: Спасибо, не понял сначала )

Comment: @VladShkuta на всякий случай дописал в конце. Пользуйтесь.